# Update TextView within custom ListView

Tags: android, listview, textview, refresh, intervals

I'm trying to update the TextView within a custom ListView at a set time interval, for example the TextView will update every 200ms however I can't figure out how to do this. The object updates with a number internally and I would like to show that in the mTitleText Textview however as the code below shows at the moment I can only achieve it when the user presses a button.

```
public class ListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
private ArrayList< Object > mObjects;
private int mNumObjs = 0;

private LayoutInflater mLayoutInflater;
private Context mContext;

public ListAdapter ( Context context, ArrayList< Object > objects ) {
    mObjects;= objects;
    mLayoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    mContext = context;
}

public int getCount() {
    return mObjects;.size();
}

public Object getItem( int position ) {
    return mObjects;.get(position);
}

public long getItemId( int position ) {
    return position;
}

public void addObject( Object obj) {
    obj.setId(mNumObjs);
    mObjects.add( obj );
    (mNumObjs);++;
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}

public void deleteObject( int pos ) {
    mObjects;.remove( pos );
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}

public View getView( final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent ) {
    final TimerView holder;

    if( convertView == null ) {
        convertView = mLayoutInflater.inflate( R.layout.customlistview, null );

        holder = new HolderView();
        holder.mListPosition = position;
        holder.mDeleteButton = (Button)convertView.findViewById(R.id.Delete);
        holder.mDeleteButton.setText( "Button No: " + position );
        holder.mDeleteButton.setOnClickListener( new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                deleteObject(holder.mListPosition);
            }
        });

        holder.mButton = (Button)convertView.findViewById(R.id.Button);
        holder.mButton.setOnClickListener( new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Object obj = mObjects.get(holder.mListPosition);

                mTitleText.setText(obj.getNum());
            }
        });

        convertView.setTag(holder);
    }
    else {
        holder = (TimerView) convertView.getTag();
    }
    holder.mListPosition = position;
    holder.mDeleteButton.setText( "Button No: " + position );

    return convertView;
}

class HolderView{
    int mListPosition;
    Button mDeleteButton;
    Button mButton;

    TextView mTitleText;
}
}
```

Comment: How about calling the invalidate method on the view whenever you update the text.  http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html

Comment: just use timer or thread for 200ms and after completed it just call notifyDataSetChanged() to your listAdapter and from getView() update the textview. Try this.

Comment: @Pramod how would I go about invalidating the view from within the Object?

Comment: @user370305 I had a go at using a handler and calling notifyDataSetChanged() at 200ms refresh rate however this did not work

Comment: @kiwijus - you could call it like you call any other method on an object.. yourViewName.invalidate() . It would suffice if you call the method on your container view instead of the individual views

Comment: @pramod calling just invalidate() doesn't work however calling invalidateviews() does. This however makes it sometimes impossible to click on the buttons within each row of the view due to lag?

Comment: Oh .. then you could consider calling invalidateviews() in a handler (i.e a separate thread) to prevent lag. http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html

Comment: I had an attempt at doing that but it still causes lag
`Handler mHandler = new Handler()
   {
        @Override
        public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
            super.handleMessage(msg);
            switch (msg.what) {
            
            case MSG_UPDATE:
             mAdapter.updateList();
             //mListView.invalidateViews();
             //mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                mHandler.sendEmptyMessageDelayed(MSG_UPDATE,REFRESH_RATE);
                break;   
                
            default:
                break;
            }
      }
    };`

Comment: @kiwijus did you try it on a real device. Emulators can be very slow :)

Comment: @Pramod I did unfortunately :( I have a feeling I'm just not meant to be able to refresh the listview in such small intervals

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay I managed to figure this out myself, if your updates don't need to be very frequent ( >1 sec ) you can use notifyDataSetChanged() however if like me you need to constantly update the listview every 200ms or so you need to iterate through the visible objects on the list view and update it.

```
private Runnable showUpdate = new Runnable(){
    public void run(){
        mAdapter.updateList();
        //mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        int count = mListView.getCount();

        for( int i = 0; i < count; i ++ )
        {
            View convertView = mListView.getChildAt( i );

            if( convertView != null )
            {
                HolderView holder = (HolderView) convertView.getTag();

                Object obj = (Object)mAdapter.getItem( holder.mListPosition );

                holder.mTitleText.setText( obj.getText() );
            }
        }
    }
};

Thread mThread = new Thread()
{
    @Override
    public void run() {
       try {
            while(true) {
                sleep(100);
                mHandler.post(showUpdate);

                //mHandler.sendEmptyMessage(MSG_UPDATE);
            }
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Update the text in your list `mObjects` and call `notifyDataSetChanged()`  on your adapter.

Comment: I've managed to get it working by doing this however this causes the listview to have some "lag" making it sometimes impossible to click on the buttons...