# Auto-refresh a ListView within a ViewPager?

Tags: android-listview, timer, android-viewpager, page-refresh, automatic-updates

**I'm having a bit of trouble approaching an auto-refresh design I want to implement.**

Currently I have a TitlePageIndicator that sets its view pager with a PagerAdapter.
Each page in the view pager is a listview that is constructed based on a list of date strings.

In my instantiateItem() method, I call an AsyncTask to load data based on the date. This works well, and loads the way I want.

**I recently changed all my listviews to PullToRefresh list views**, in order to make sure a user could update the data on a date they wished to have the most up-to-date info on. *(This also works the way I desire).*

***However now I want to somehow refresh a certain date in the view pager (Current date for instance) - every 60 seconds. So I'm not refreshing all the listivews in the viewpager, i'm just refreshing the one I want.***

I started making a timer thread based on this :

[Update TextView within custom ListView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7686509/update-textview-within-custom-listview)

But soon got very stumped and I'm not sure what to do next..

**Can someone point me in the right direction?**